# Passing 3 dimensional and one dimensional features to neural network with PyTorch Dataloader

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have examples with size 2x8x8 as tensor and I'm using PyTorch Dataloader for them. But now I want to add an additional 1 dim tensor with size 1 (a single number) as input too.

So I have two input parameters for the neural network, a multidimensional for convolutional layers and an additional one that I will concatenate later.

Probably I could use two dataloader, for every tensor shape one, but than I could not shuffle them.

How can I use a single PyTorch Dataloader for this two different input tensors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about the dataloader, this should be done in the your dataset. Implement your own dataset by making it inherit from `torch.util.data.Dataset` (you need to implement `__len__` and `__getitem__`). Make your `__getitem__`method return both your tensors, and you should be fine.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) if  you need.